# How to use paste in for loop in R? to change exif data of photos

Tags: r, metadata, system, paste, exif

I am working on a MacOS Big Sur 11.6 with R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)

I am trying to use paste() within a for loop but I need the values within the paste function to change with each iteration.

I have a data frame like this:

```
            pathname S
1 user/folder/photo1 A
2 user/folder/photo2 B
3 user/folder/photo3 C
```

and I am trying to add an EXIF Comment tag to the metadata of my photos. I would like the Comment tag to change based on the S column value. I have code like this:

```
for(i in df$pathname){
  x <- df$S[i]
  sysCommand <- paste("exiftool -Comment=x i")
  system(sysCommand)
}
```

The inputs (i.e. x and i) within the paste function should change as it goes through the list.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try: `paste0("exiftool -Comment=", x, " ", i)`

Comment: Build the string like any other character value: `sysCommand <- paste0("exiftool -Comment=", x, " ", i)`. You probably want to make sure that `x` doesn't have any spaces or you may wind up with an invalid command.

Comment: You could also use the [**`glue`**](https://glue.tidyverse.org) package: `sysCommand <- glue::glue("exiftool -Comment={x} {i}")`.  You just need to "embrace" (`{ }`) the variable names within the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Where You Went Wrong

Your interpretation of [`paste()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/paste.html) is flawed.  This function takes R *objects* and concatenates their string representations.

So given

```
name <- "Rogue"
```

then the code

```
paste("Hi name!", "  How are you?")
```

will simply concatenate the string objects `"Hi name!"` and `"  How are you?"` to yield

```
[1] "Hi name!  How are you?"
```

To substitute in the `name`, one must use the `name` *object*

```
paste("Hi ", name, "!", "  How are you?")
#            ^^^^
```

to obtain

```
[1] "Hi Rogue!  How are you?"
```

## Solution 1: Use `paste()` *Correctly*

As the comments rightly suggest, the proper use of `paste()` would be

```
  # ...

  sysCommand <- paste("exiftool -Comment=", x, " ", i, sep = "")
  #                                                    ^^^^^^^^
  #                                                    Avoid unwanted spaces.

  # ...
```

with care to include the argument `sep = ""`, and thus avoid extra spaces like those in `"exiftool -Comment= A   1"`.  Each result should look like this:

```
[1] "exiftool -Comment=A 1"
```

### Note

The [`paste0()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/paste.html) function omits extra spaces automatically, so it has no need for `sep = ""`.

## Solution 2: The **`glue`** Package

To make things work the way you expected, you could use the [**`glue`**](https://glue.tidyverse.org/) package.

```
  # ...

  sysCommand <- glue::glue("exiftool -Comment={x} {i}")

  # ...
```

with care to "embrace" every variable name with `{ }`. Each result should look like

```
exiftool -Comment=A 1
```

a `glue` object that is also a normal string.

## Note

As I mention in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715081/how-to-use-paste-in-for-loop-in-r-to-change-exif-data-of-photos/69715325#comment123228421_69715325)

> You've extracted your data incorrectly with `for(i in df$pathname)` and `df$S[i]`. When you use `i` in `df$pathname`, you're iterating with `i` over the **strings** `"user/folder/photo1"`, `"user/folder/photo2"`, and so forth. By contrast, `df$S[i]` expects a **number** within the `[ ]`, as it attempts to take the value in the `i`th place of column `S`. Since it can't interpret a string like `"user/folder/photo1"` as a `numeric` index, the operation `df$S[i]` returns an `NA` value...which `paste()` [interprets as the string `"NA"`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/paste.html#heading-3).

your original code **also** erred logically when accessing the data in `df`. The nifty [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69715422) by [@dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792244) offers a cleanly vectorized solution to this error.

That said, your [correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715081/how-to-use-paste-in-for-loop-in-r-to-change-exif-data-of-photos/69715325#comment123228526_69715325://stackoverflow.com/posts/69715325/timeline#comment_123228526) does well in fixing this issue

```
for(i in 1:length(df$pathname)){
  #for each photo
  x <- df$S[i]
  pathname <- df$pathname[i]

  syscommand <- paste("exiftool -Comment=", site, " ", pathname, sep = "")   
  system(syscommand)
}
```

and it retains the structure of your original loop.  I'm happy to hear it works!

Comment: Thank you, I tried both solutions but I get NAs for Comment

Comment: You've extracted your data incorrectly with `for(i in df$pathname)` and `df$S[i]`.  When you use `i in df$pathname`, you're iterating with `i` over the **strings** `"user/folder/photo1"`, `"user/folder/photo2"`, and so forth.  By contrast, `df$S[i]` expects a **number** within the `[ ]`, as it attempts to take the value in the `i`th place of column `S`.  Since it can't interpret a string like `"user/folder/photo1"` as a `numeric` index, the operation `df$S[i]` returns an `NA` value...which `paste()` [interprets as the string `"NA"`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/paste.html#heading-3).

Comment: thank you for the paste lesson. This seems to work: 
`for(i in 1:length(df$pathname)){
  #for each photo
  x <- df$S[i]
  pathname <- df$pathname[i]
 syscommand <- paste("exiftool -Comment=", site, " ", pathname, sep = "")
  system(syscommand)
} `

Comment: @Rogue Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon @Greg's excellent explanation of the paste function.  There are a couple of flaws in the logic related to accessing the data in the data frame.

Also is `paste()` is a vectorized function, it is easier to make a vector of the system commands and then just use the loop just to execute the commands.  This avoids with dealing with the subscripts.

```
data<- read.table(header=TRUE, text="          pathname S
user/folder/photo1 A
user/folder/photo2 B
user/folder/photo3 C")


#paste is vectorized function
# create a list of all of the requested system commands
commands <-paste0("exiftool -Comment=", data$S, " ", data$pathname) 

#loop through the vectors of command
for (i in commands) {
   print(i)  #debugging
  system(i)  
}
```

Comment: Nice job vectorizing the solution!